# Why is java server with a JFrame working in debug mode but not in normal execution mode?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, debugging, server

My main server loop below works perfectly when I step through it in debug mode:

- when the start button is pressed the server starts with the socket the user wrote in the textfield and the start button is disabled
- when the server starts a message is displayed on the big textarea indicating the port and address on which it is running
- when a client connects to it a message is displayed indicating the connection was established
- the server doesn't get stuck in any other loop except the main one, which is exited only when the user chooses to exit

But when I run the program in normal mode and the start button is pressed all that happens is:

- the start button gets disabled
- no messages appears
- clients can't connect to the specified socket

Any help appreciated.

```
public class ServerLoop {
    static boolean running;
    static int currentState=0;
    static int port;
    static ServerSocket server = null;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        MainServer main = new MainServer();
        while (true) {
            currentState = main.getCurrentState();
            switch (currentState) {
            case 1:
                port = main.getPortnumber();
                JTextArea text = main.getTextArea();
                String temp = text.getText();
                temp = temp + "Portnumber: "+ port +"\n" + 
                    "Server ip-address: " + main.getIpAddress()+ "\n";
                main.updateText(temp);
                server = new ServerSocket(port);
                currentState++;
                break;

            case 2:
                Socket clientConnection = server.accept();
                text = main.getTextArea();
                temp = text.getText();
                temp = temp + "Connection with: " +
                    clientConnection.getInetAddress().getHostName() +
                    "established. \n";
                main.updateText(temp);
                new ClientConnected(clientConnection);
                break;

            case 3:
                text = main.getTextArea();
                temp = text.getText();
                temp = temp + "Server shutting down...\n";
                main.updateText(temp);
                server.close();
                text = main.getTextArea();
                temp = text.getText();
                temp = temp + "Server shutdown\n";
                main.updateText(temp);
                main.setIdle(true);
                currentState=0;
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This class creates the interface for the server its just a simple one with one large textarea, one small textfield and 2 buttons with listeners.

If I have to guess its the server loop and actionlisteners on the buttons that are hating each other, but I don't understand why it is working in debug mode.

```
public class MainServer extends JFrame {
    JTextArea mainTextfield;
    String k = "";
    JTextField portnumber;
    JFrame frame;
    JButton start,close;
    int currentState = 0;
    int porten;
    boolean idle = true;

    public MainServer() {
        frame = new JFrame("ArenanServer v1.0");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 550);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        mainTextfield = new JTextArea();
        mainTextfield.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(585,450));
        mainTextfield.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        mainTextfield.setOpaque(true);
        mainTextfield.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
        mainTextfield.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(mainTextfield)
        frame.add(scroll);

        JLabel port = new JLabel();
        port.setText("Port: ");
        frame.add(port);

        portnumber = new JTextField();
        portnumber.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
        portnumber.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,25));
        portnumber.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(5));
        frame.add(portnumber);

        ////I think this might be a problem with the actionlisteners on buttons//
        start = new JButton("Start server");
        close = new JButton("Close server");

        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (portnumber.getText().length()>0) {
                    porten = Integer.parseInt(portnumber.getText());
                    start.setEnabled(false);
                    close.setEnabled(true);
                    currentState = 1;
                    idle=false;
                } 
                else {
                    k = mainTextfield.getText();
                    k = k + "Please enter a port number.\n";
                    updateText(k);
                }
            }
         });

    close.setEnabled(false);
    close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            currentState = 3;
            start.setEnabled(true);
            close.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    frame.add(start);
    frame.add(close);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

These are some functions made to increase the communication between the main loop and the interface they are placed in the same class as the interface.

```
protected JButton getStartButton() {
    return start;
}
protected JButton getCloseButton() {
    return close;
}
protected int getPortnumber() {
    return porten;
}

protected JTextArea getTextArea() {
    return mainTextfield;
}
protected JFrame getFrame() {
    return frame;
}
protected boolean updateText(String l) {
    mainTextfield.setText(l);
    frame.repaint();
    if (mainTextfield.getText().equals(l)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
protected boolean updateview() {
    frame.repaint();
    return true;
}
protected int getCurrentState() {
    if (idle) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (currentState != 1) {
            return currentState;
        } else {
            currentState++;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
protected void setIdle(boolean t) {
    idle = t;
}
```

[Picture of what it looks like in both runs after pressing the start button and trying to connect to the socket, debug mode to the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LZaQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

While reviewing your question I edited it to improve its readability. I had to reformat your code as the mix of tabs and spaces and inconsistent indentation screwed up the StackOverflow code parser.

While doing that I *think* I found the answer: the closing of the curly bracket from 
`public MainServer() {` and the closing of the 1st round bracket from `start.addActionListener(new ActionListener()` are incorrectly crossed with each-other.

This is what you have:

```
    public MainServer() {
        ...
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            ...                
        }
    });
```

This is what I *think* you should have:

```
    public MainServer() {
        ...
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            ...                
        });
    }
```

I guess lessons to be learned:

- code formatting is important - you'd have found the error as well while trying to be consistent in code formatting
- not a good idea to mix tabs and spaces for indentation
- spaces are better for indentation - friendlier to the StackOverflow editor :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, this is my first time ever using stackoverflow i just copy/pasted my code from eclipse into the editor here and then bombarded every line with spaces. maybe not the best way to go. But thank you for editing my question looks alot better. To your answer, if im understanding you correctly you mean that "});" should be like this ")};" at the start.addActionListenter? Or have i understood you incorrectly? :)
If i try that i get lots of errors. Do you have any other ideas? :) thanks

Comment: I clarified the answer

Comment: I could see what you mean now. In eclipse what you suggest is what i have. I found there was one to many "}" by the point you mentioned. I edited that out. Do you have any other ideas what might be the problem?